# SQL Server injection point

Tags: sql-server, code-injection

While doing penetration tests I found a SQL injection point in SQL Server.

I manage to use this

```
' UNION ALL SELECT 
null,null,null,null,null,null,
null,null,null,null,null,null,
null,null,null,null,null,null,
null,null,null,null,null,null,
null,null,null,null,null,null,
null,null,email 
from customers where customer_id =10--
```

This is giving me the email for user ID 10. If I change the ID number it will give me other results.

Is there any way to get all the emails in one query?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Using

```
' or 1=convert(int,(select top 1 email from customers))--
```

I am getting the first email. By changing to 10 for example I am getting

> [OleDbException (0x80004005): Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.]

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean to get different sets of results by passing multiple custimer ids?

Comment: Try `where customer_id=customer_id`

Comment: This returns the email of user ID 1

Comment: can you the code before the `UNION ALL` and the conditions after it if any

Comment: Hoping you're doing this for legit purposes?!

Comment: Only if the resulting web pages can render more than one row. If not then no.

Answer (score 2):

Just leave the `where` clause off altogether. It's the thing limiting what's coming out of the partial query. In other words, something like:

```
' union all select <too many nulls to retype>, email from customers --
```

If that only gets you one row then it's a fairly safe bet that the code running the website is enforcing that limit, such as if appending something like `fetch first row only` or `limit 1` or something like that.

If that's the case, you'll need to keep the `where` clause in and automate the attack one ID at a time. You may also need to ensure that the "real" row is after the injection-obtained row so that the former won't be retrieved in preference to the the latter. A lookup key that you *know* isn't in the database would do the trick.

Comment: Removing  where customer_id =10 still returns me the email of ID 1
Not working...

Comment: So there is no way you believe?
It will have to be done one by one?

Comment: @b.n., see the update. Based on assumed knowledge (but relatively educated), more than likely this is caused by further restrictions on the code. Hence one at a time is probably the best way to go. That doesn't mean manual effort, you can always automate web page scraping.

Comment: Its on POST on login field

Answer (score 0):

You could try and stuff them all into a CSV, depending on the length of the output? That means if you're limited to one row you should get it back?

Try missing out the where clause and using the following:

```
' union all select <nulls>, SUBSTRING((select ',' + email from customer order by email for xml path('')), 2, 1000000) --
```

Comment: [OleDbException (0x80004005): String or binary data would be truncated.]

Comment: Then the result is too long being returned (it must be doing something else with the returned data), you could try tweaking the 1000000 (the length of the string to be returned), you more than likely wont get all of your information back in this case, but you could now batch it or just alter the select as you need to (top x rows etc)

Answer (score 0):

You specify this `WHERE` clause to return all customers:

```
WHERE customer_id = customer_id--
```